# Procesar formularios en Spring Boot

Tags: java, mvc, formularios, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo un problema con este formulario. Sucede que yo quiero recuperar la información pero al redirigirme a la página en la que debe salir dicha información, todos los campos aparecen como nulos. La idea es que se muestre el objeto que cree en el formulario, pero como pueden ver, aparecen en nulo. He revisado varios artículos y no he podido encontrar la solución a este problema. Pd: Los dos primeros objetos ya están instanciados dentro del controlador de la pagina index.

[image: Formulario]

[image: Pagina con resultado]

Controlador del Formulario

```java
@Controller
public class FormController {
    
    // Redirige al formulario
    @GetMapping("home/newcar")
    public ModelAndView form() {
        return new ModelAndView(Pages.FORM).addObject("car", new Car());
    }
    // Redirige a el index pero con el nuevo objeto agregado
    @PostMapping("home/addnewcar")
    public ModelAndView addNewCar(Car car) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(Pages.INDEX);
        List<Car> cars = IndexController.getCars();
        cars.add(car);
        modelAndView.addObject("cars", cars);
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

```java
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    // Retorna una nueva lista de objetos del modelo "Car"
    public static List<Car> getCars() {
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(new Car(/*id*/ 1, /*descripcion*/ "Liviano y rápido. El perfecto para viajes largos", /*marca*/ "Mazda", /*placa*/ "TSA-123", /*modelo*/"2013", /*img*/ "https://noticias.coches.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Mazda-3-2013-07.jpg"));
        cars.add(new Car(2, "Aguanta todo. 4X4 todo terreno", "Chevrolet", "XSE-241", "2020", "https://www.elcarrocolombiano.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/20190326-CHEVROLET-MONZA-2020-CARACTERISTICAS-VERSIONES-Y-PRECIOS-EN-CHINA-01.jpg"));
        return cars;
    }

    /Redirige hacia el index con los objetos creados.
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(Pages.INDEX);
        modelAndView.addObject("cars", getCars());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Formulario

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="container" th:action="@{/home/addnewcar}" th:object="${car}" method="post">
        <div class="col">
            <input th:field="*{marca}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Marca" aria-label="First name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input th:field="*{modelo}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Modelo" aria-label="Last name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input th:field="*{placa}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Placa" aria-label="Last name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input th:field="*{img}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Imagen" aria-label="Last name"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input th:field="*{descripcion}" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Informacion Adicional" aria-label="Last name"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Index

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/index.css}">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <section>
        <h3>HERE'S THE ICON</h3>
      </section>
      <section>Search</section>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div th:each=" car : ${cars}" class="card">
        <img th:src="${car.img}" alt="mazda-2019">
        <h3 th:text="${car.marca} + ' ' + ${car.modelo}" class="card-title"></h3>
        <p th:text="${car.descripcion}" class="card-description"></p>
        <span>Placa: <h4 th:text="${car.placa}" class="car-add-info"></h4></span>
        <div class="bottons"><a th:href="@{/home/cars/} + ${car.id}">Más info</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Al objeto `Car` usado como parámetro en tu método `addNewCar` le hace falta la anotación `@ModelAttribute`:

`public ModelAndView addNewCar(@ModelAttribute Car car)`

La anotación mencionada permite la persistencia entre capas, te sugiero leer [la documentación](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation#2-as-a-method-argument) al respecto.

Comment: Ya lo hice, no funcionó. He leído bastante sobre eso y nada que encuentro la falla.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta por mi cuenta. Examiné bien, y sucede que no tenía métodos setters en el modelo Car. Pensé, que por buenas practicas, las variables privadas no debían tener setters y getters, porque sino entonces se debería dejar publica esa variable. Pero, por alguna razón, Spring Boot detecta esos métodos.

```java
package com.java.primer_programa.models;

public class Car {
    String descripcion, marca, placa, modelo, img;
    int id;

    public Car() {}

    public Car(int id, String descripcion, String marca, String placa, String modelo, String img) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.marca = marca;
        this.placa = placa;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }
}
```

Después de agregar esto, si se mostraron los resultados.
[image: Resultado]

Comment: Al no haber compartido el código de tu clase `Car` se interpretó que el problema podría radicar en la configuración de Spring o Thymeleaf, te recomiendo revisar el tema de la encapsulación en Java, ya que al parecer tenías conceptos erróneos sobre el mismo. Por buenas prácticas en tu modelado `Car` cada variable debe ser declarada de manera independiente y con el modificador de acceso `private`, en tu ejemplo, al no contar con modificadores de acceso, por default tus variables son `public`, provocando que los métodos `getter` y `setter` no tengan sentido.